# is it possible to create anonymous type generics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous-types

I've built a pagination class that works well for a specific data type, 
but now I need to make the type dynamic

here is my code

```
public class Pagination {
    public IQueryable<Character> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<Character> items, int pageSize) {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<Character> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```

as you can see, this pagination class works only for 'Character', is it possible to create anonymous data type and invoke generic methods such as Skip and Take?

Comment: Looks like a lot of us noticed this at the same time.

Comment: Wow, Exactly. Most of your answers are valid!Thanks a lot, but I can only tick 1...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create the class as a **generic** class:

```
public class Pagination<T> {
    public IQueryable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize) {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should have the qualification "`where T : class`"

Comment: @ScottSEA why? I don't think that constraint is absolutely required.

Answer (score 3):

You just use generics for a base class and inherit, implementing the class.

```
public class Pagination <T> where T : class
```

Then put T in all places you currently have the Character class

Answer (score 1):

this should be pretty simple... 
try this...

```
public class Pagination<_type> 
{
    public IQueryable<_type> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<_type> items, int pageSize) {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<_type> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```

you might want to add a constraint on _type, like this (makes it so _type MUST be a class):

```
public class Pagination< _type > where _type : class
```

Answer (score 1):

This generic class should do the job.

```
public class Pagination<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize)
    {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I would do it the following way:

1. Hide the implementation, only expose an interface:

   ```
   public interface IPagination<T>
   {
       int PageSize { get; set; }
       int TotalPages { get; }
       IQueryable<T> GetPage(int page);
   }
   ```
2. Make the `Pagination` class generic and only an internal implementation (the outside only sees the interface)

   ```
   public class Pagination<T> : IPagination<T> {
       public IQueryable<T> Items { get; set; }

       public int PageSize { get; set; }

       public int TotalPages {
           get {
                       if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                       return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
                   else
                       return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
               }
           }

           internal Pagination(IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize) {
               this.PageSize = pageSize;
               this.Items = items;
           }

           public IQueryable<T> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
               pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
               return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
           }
   }
   ```
3. Offer an extension method to convert:

   ```
    public static IPagination<T> AsPagination (this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize)
    {
        if(source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return new Pagination<T>(source, pageSize);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible but it's typically only useful within a method body.  For example

```
var array = new[] {
  new { Name = "Jared", Age = 30 },
  new { Name = "Bob", Age = 21 }
};
var query = array.Skip(1).Take(1);
```

This becomes problematic to pass between methods though because there is no way to state the name of an anonymous type hence nothing to put in for the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>`.  It's possible to do with generic tricks but it doesn't appear to fit what you need for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
public class Pagination<T> {
    public IQueryable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize) {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```

I'm not certain I see the correlation with anonymous types? Why do you need that to get this type to work for types other than `Character`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public class Pagination<T> where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get {
            if (this.Items.Count() % this.PageSize == 0)
                return this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize;
            else
                return (this.Items.Count() / this.PageSize) + 1;
        }
    }

    public Pagination(IQueryable<T> items, int pageSize) {
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        pageNumber = pageNumber - 1;
        return this.Items.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNumber).Take(this.PageSize);
    }
}
```